# Wait a promise end before continue

Tags: web3js, metamask

i try to create a map with (address => bool) with web3js. I want to know if the address is a contract owner.
So, i have to call "owners" function in my solidity contract.
As you can see below :

```
let allAccountInfo = new Map();
let localAccount = web3.eth.accounts;

    for(account in localAccount){

        MyContract.owners(localAccount[account],function(error,result){

            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                allAccountInfo.set(account,result);
            }

        });

    }
    console.log(allAccountInfo);
```

Because MyContract.Function return a promise, this code don't work. I have to wait the promises end before loop... with "await" ?

```
 let allAccountInfo = new Map();
 let localAccount = web3.eth.accounts;

     for(account in localAccount){
            result = await MyContract.owners(localAccount[account])
            allAccountInfo.set(account,result);
     }
  console.log(allAccountInfo);
```

But when i do this, i get this error :

> Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods
>   like eth_call without a callback parameter.

Do you know a solution ?
Thanks,

Comment: Would be helpful if you stated which line of code throws this exception.

Comment: It's the line with "await" keyword.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to add `.call(...)` or `.send(...)` at the end of that line (depending on whether this function is constant or state-changing).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i've decided to switch to Web3js 1.0 that handle await correctly.